# Есть ли в Java API для работы с JSON?

Tags: java, json

Какие существуют стандартные `api` по работе с `json`?
Чтобы все шло из коробки, то есть, из обычного `java jdk 1.7`

В `php` сразу в коробке есть функции по работе с json, в Java разве нет?

Comment: [Interface JsonObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html)

Comment: И где мне искать javax, из пакетов у меня тольк java

Comment: Ваш компилятор не видит этот интерфейс?

Comment: Нет не видит, вот я и спрашиваю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html)
Может не до конца понял вопрос, но вот по идее.

Comment: Мне нужен стандартный, предоставляемый jdk 1.7 json, и существует ли такой? Если нет, то это плоховато то прийдется таскать за сабой файлик который будет предоставлять api на джаве для json

Comment: Насколько помню, то нет такого.

Comment: Хм, плохо, тогда подскажите ссылку на Jar

Comment: А не, спс, скачал тут http://sourceforge.net/projects/json-lib/files/json-lib/json-lib-2.2.2/

Comment: Только хотел эту ссылку сбросить. Что же, удачи, сам сейчас с сокетами работаю. Вот еще ссылка на всякий случай: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm

Answer (score 3):

К сожалению, в настоящий момент нет никакого встроенного JSON API в Java. Разработчики хотели добавить стандартизированный JSON API в Java 9, но потом решили добавить другие важные фичи, а эту вычеркнуть из списка. Неизвестно, так же, будет ли он в Java 10.

А пока нам придётся пользоваться отдельными библиотеками.

Такими, как [javax.json](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/package-summary.html), который можно взять из [maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json/javax.json-api/1.0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

или [Org.JSON](http://www.json.org/java/index.html), который можно взять из [maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20151123)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20151123</version>
</dependency>
```

и другими библиотеками.

[Полезная ссылка по теме из английского Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

> в Java разве нет?

Есть в [Java EE](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/), либо используя библиотеки GSON (от гугла) или jackson.

Тут надо понимать, что в Java вообще "модно" использовать сторонние библиотеки, а на уровне языка давать только общий API (как, например, JPA - это ORM для языка Java, на уровне самого языка есть только интерфейсы). Такая "мода" позволяет развиваться большому количеству альтернативных библиотек. Поэтому просто используйте, скажем, maven и возможность генерировать все пакеты jar'ов в одном zip файле и т.п.